# How to interpret audio bytes?

Tags: java, audio-analysis

I want to write a Voice Stress Analysis tool. I'm opening the audio stream for reading:

```
TargetDataLine line;
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat((float) 44100, 16, 1, true, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
line.open(format);
// Begin audio capture.
line.start();
```

and then looping:

```
// Read the next chunk of data from the TargetDataLine.
numBytesRead = line.read(externalData, 0, externalData.length);
```

I get an array with bytes as externalData is defined as follows:

```
public static byte[] externalData = new byte[1024];
```

What I want to know is how to interpret this data? I tried to plot it by byte value, but I guess it's wrong. [image: Plotted bytes]

X axis is time and Y axis is byte value.

PS: Where can I find more information about McQuiston-Ford algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain wave pattern of a audio file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024683/obtain-wave-pattern-of-a-audio-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert bytes into amplitude and plot those. See this question about how to dot it: [Obtain wave pattern of a audio file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024683/obtain-wave-pattern-of-a-audio-file-in-java/13024779#13024779)

as for the algorithm, wikipedia says its pseudescience, I doubt there's gonna be much about it in public domain.

Comment: Measuring stress is possible, but using that information for lie detection is not scientifically proven.